# compare void* with uint16_t

Tags: c++, gcc, gcc4.6

In some legacy code, which compiles fine on GCC 4.6 (with `-fpermissive`), I have this:

```
uint16_t a = 0;
void* b = ...;

if(b == a) // ...
```

Is this comparison well-defined on GCC 4.6? Does it downcast to 16 bits or upcast to 32/64 bits?

Comment: If I remember correctly, this is valid in C but not in C++; I might be utterly wrong though...

Comment: GCC will fail to compile this without the -fpermissive option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it up-casts the 16 bit integer to match the pointer size.
Running the following code outputs `"upcast"`

```
uint16_t a = 1;
void* b = (void*)0x10001;
(b == a) ? printf("downcast") : printf("upcast");
```

Comment: Is that with GCC 4.6?

Comment: Thanks a lot! You should add that link to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Although this isn't explicitly written in the C++11 standard (N3337 draft), I was able to come up with this (emphasis mine).

> **§5.9 Relational operators**
>
> Pointers to objects or functions *of the same type* (after pointer conversions) can be compared, with a result defined as follows
>
> — If two pointers ...
>
> — If two pointers ...
>
> — If two pointers ...
>
> — If two pointers ...
>
> — If two pointers ...
>
> — *Other pointer comparisons are unspecified.*

Now for the equality part:

> **§5.10 Equality operators**
>
> The == (equal to) and the != (not equal to) operators *have the same semantic restrictions, conversions, and result type as the relational operators* except for their lower precedence and truth-value result.

By this I believe that *such a comparison is unspecified*.

Comment: So you say that it is undefined in the C++ standard. But how would GCC 4.6 do it?

Comment: I believe that it is _unspecified_ by the standard, not _undefined_. However, in both cases an implemenation (like GCC) is free to do what it may; please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

Comment: I know. But my question is, what does it do.

Answer (score 0):

It may compile or may not (not sure, it depends on the compiler and compiler options)
In any case the cast will be performed like:

```
if( b == (void*)a )
{
}
```

Note that upcasting/downcasting is not the correct word to use because it is related to classes, in this case is just type conversions.